# Facebook comments plugin, same comments on Facebook page and on website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

One client noted he was getting less comments in his blog and more in his Facebook page, so he asked me whether he could share the same comments in both his company page and website.

Basically if somebody comments in his facebook page the comment should be visible on the blog comments and vice-versa. Is this possible?

Comment: No using the Comments plugin, no. You’d have to implement this yourself via FB API.

Comment: Hi @CBroe for this I would have to use FB API + My Custom Comments right? How would this work? I know I can retrieve comments in FB through API and add them to comments on my site, however how could I take comments from my site to facebook?

Comment: I ask because I doubt there is a an API interface to comment on behalf of a user.